# AdMob 7.51 causes crash in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, admob

I'm trying to implement AdMob 7.51 in a new project in Swift.
Xcode version 11
Admob version 7.51.0

I've added the Admob files as such
[image]

Added to info.plist:
[image]

Added -ObjC to Linker:
[image]

That is, following the guide at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

That is all, I've not even implemented 'import GoogleMobileAds'
However, when I run the app (nothing else is there, so the app is clean), I get this error:

[image]
[image]

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The format in info.plist was wrong...